# What is the proper comparison operator to use. The add button should not accept the users input if the default value which is 0 is still selected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

The name and email input fields are already working, what is the proper comparison operator or if else statement to use so that if the default value which is 0 is still selected, the user cannot proceed and the add button will not accept the input?

```
$("#anchAddStudent").click(function() {
  var id = $('#last').val();
  console.log(id)
  var name = $('#inputName').val();
  var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
  var department_id = $('#selectDepartment').val();
  let last = $('#last').val()
  var data = {
    'name': $('#inputName').val(),
    'email': $('#inputEmail').val(),
    'department_id': $('#selectDepartment').val()
  }
  console.log(data);

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/students",
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {

      function IsEmail(email) {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        if (!regex.test(email)) {

          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }

      if (response.status == 400) {

        if (email.indexOf("@") < 0 || email.indexOf(".") < 0) {
          $("#spanInputEmail").removeClass('hideme');
          $("#inputEmail").addClass('borderColor');
        }

        if (name == "") {
          $("#spanInputName").removeClass('hideme');
          $("#inputName").addClass('borderColor');
        }

        if (department_id == 0) {
          $("#spanSelectDept").removeClass('hideme');
          console.log(department_id);
        }

      } else {

        $('#last').val(parseInt(last) + 1);
        $('#saveform_errList').html("");
        $('#success_message').addClass('alert alert-success');
        $('#success_message').text(response.message);
        $("#inputForm").find('input').val("");

        $("#inputName").val('');
        $("#inputEmail").val('');
        $("#selectDepartment").val('');

        // append row inside the table
        $("table tbody").append(
          `<tr>
                <td class='studentId'>${id}.</td>
                <td class='studentName'>${name}</td>
                <td class='studentEmail'>${email}</td>
                <td class='studentDept'>${response.dept_name}</td>
                <td class='studActions' data-studId='${response.id}' data-name='${name}' data-email='${email}' data-dept='${response.dept_name}' data-deptId='${department_id}' data-studDept='${department_id}'>
                <button type='button' value='${response.id}' data-id='{{ ${response.id} }}' class='btnDeleteStudent btn btn-danger btn-sm float-end'>Delete</button>
                <button type='button' class='btnEditStudent btn btn-primary btn-sm float-end'>Edit</button>
                <button type='button' class='btnCancelEditStudent btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-end hideme'>Cancel</button>
                <button type='button' class='btnUpdateStudent btn btn-primary btn-sm float-end                                hideme'>Update</button>
                </td>;
            </tr>`
        )
      }
    }
  });
});
```

the name and email input fields are already working, what is the proper comparison operator or if else statement to use so that if the default value which is 0 is still selected, the user cannot proceed and the add button will not accept the input? in my case, the add button is still accepting the even tho it is in default. what should i change in my code? please help

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about the value of department_id, that if it's value is zero(0), it should not proceed the code further.
you can do it with return. Like

```js
function test() {
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var useremail = $('#useremail').val();
  var department_id = $('#department_id').val();
  alert(department_id);
  if(department_id == 0){
  //here you can write your code, that should execute if department_id is zero
          $("#demo").text('Sorry value is zero');
          return;
  }
  
  alert("Alert to execute after if condition, only if the if  condition does not run");
}
function showDepartment() {
    $('#demo').text(
    'department_id : '+ $('#department_id').val()
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="username" type="text" placeholder='Enter name' /> <br>
<input id="useremail" type="email" placeholder='Enter Email' /> <br>

<select name="department" id="department_id" onchange="showDepartment()" >
  <option value="0" selected >Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">Department 1</option>
  <option value="2">Department 2</option>
  <option value="3">Department 3</option>
</select>

<br> 

<p id="demo"> </p>
<button onclick="test()"> Click Me </button>
```

Comment: *it is a `select` element* - please include all relevant code in the question.  See [mcve].  There's no way to guess that from the question.

Comment: Also, the type of element is irrelevant as it's the check of the `value`, which this answer provides you.

Comment: @Haris run this in the console: `var department_id = 0; console.log(department_id == 0, department_id == "0")`  If you're using "==" then `0 == "0"` already